# Select the second observation per group in R

Tags: r

I feel like this should be straightforward, but I can't figure it out. I want to select the second observation by group from a data frame.

For example:

```
Row Number    Email 
           1             xxxx
           2             xxxx
           3             xxxx
           4             xxxx
           5             xxxx
           6             yyyy
           7             yyyy
           8             zzzz
           9             zzzz
           10            zzzz
           11            zzzz
           12            zzzz
```

And I want:

```
Row Number    Email 
           2             xxxx
           7             yyyy
           9             zzzz
```

It appears that data.table solution and aggregate solution are skipping groups of emails that they should be capturing. Here are the first six second rows that it should capture:

```
Row Number   emails   expected output   actual output
1            aaaa
2            aaaa     aaaa              aaaa
3            aaaa
4            aaaa
5            aaaa
6            aaaa
7            aaaa
8            bbbb
9            bbbb     bbbb              bbbb
10           cccc
11           cccc     cccc              cccc
12           cccc
13           cccc
14           cccc
15           cccc
16           cccc
17           dddd     NA
18           eeee
19           eeee     eeee
20           eeee
21           ffff
22           ffff     ffff              ffff
```

email 'eeee' has one row in the dataset so I would expect an NA row for this one. email 'dddd' has three rows in the original dataset so I would expect the second row for this email, but it's not there.

Comment: Per group of emails. For all the emails that equal "xxxx", select the second observation. Sorry perhaps I'm misusing the word. They are ordered by time in my full dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[2L], by = Email]
#    Email Row.Number
# 1:  xxxx          2
# 2:  yyyy          7
# 3:  zzzz          9
```

Or with base R

```
aggregate(. ~ Email, df, function(x) x[2L])
#   Email Row.Number
# 1  xxxx          2
# 2  yyyy          7
# 3  zzzz          9
```

---

**EDIT**: With the new data set

```
df <- read.table(text = "'Row Number'   emails
                1            aaaa
                 2            aaaa             
                 3            aaaa
                 4            aaaa
                 5            aaaa
                 6            aaaa
                 7            aaaa
                 8            bbbb
                 9            bbbb  
                 10           cccc
                 11           cccc   
                 12           cccc
                 13           cccc
                 14           cccc
                 15           cccc
                 16           cccc
                 17           dddd
                 18           eeee
                 19           eeee     
                 20           eeee
                 21           ffff
                 22           ffff", header = TRUE)
```

Running the code

```
setDT(df)[, .SD[2L], by = emails]
#    emails Row.Number
# 1:   aaaa          2
# 2:   bbbb          9
# 3:   cccc         11
# 4:   dddd         NA
# 5:   eeee         19
# 6:   ffff         22
```

Comment: Could I alter the "2L" to "3L" and that would select the third observation per email group? It doesn't appear to working like that.

Comment: Yes. You can alter `2L` to `3L` and it will select the third observation within each group. Only problem that you don't have 3 observations within the `yyyy` group so it will return `NA` for that specific group.

Comment: That's ok. Thank you! For my full dataset, it looks like it's working for some email addresses, but not all of them. It takes the 2nd observation for some, but not for every unique email address. Any idea why it would be doing this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you show an example when this is not working?

Comment: I've edited my original post. Please let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: You only have one observation for each email in the new data. What is the expected output?

Comment: My code returns the expected output with your new data set. See my edit.

Comment: Totally my fault, I was eliminating the ones with NAs but the syntax I was using was eliminating more than necessary. Not sure why so I just selected the non-NA cases using sqldf.

Answer (score 4):

Try this. No packages needed:

```
subset(DF, ave(RowNumber, Email, FUN = seq_along) == 2)
```

or

```
DF[ ave(DF$RowNumber, DF$Email, FUN = seq_along) == 2, ]
```

Using the data shown under Note below either of these produces three rows:

```
  RowNumber Email
2         2  xxxx
7         7  yyyy
9         9  zzzz
```

The sample data has no single row groups and the  question did not specify how to handle such groups but these answers produce no rows for such groups.  I think you will find that some of the answers give the same result whereas others give a row with the `RowNumber` field set to `NA`.

**Note:**

We used this for the input data `DF`:

```
Lines <- "RowNumber    Email 
           1             xxxx
           2             xxxx
           3             xxxx
           4             xxxx
           5             xxxx
           6             yyyy
           7             yyyy
           8             zzzz
           9             zzzz
           10            zzzz
           11            zzzz
           12            zzzz"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Next time please supply the code to create the input data in the question.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but your solutions only return one observation.

Comment: No. Using the input data shown they produce the three rows shown.

Answer (score 3):

you can try this using the package `dplyr`

```
d <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
Number    Email 
           1             xxxx
           2             xxxx
           3             xxxx
           4             xxxx
           5             xxxx
           6             yyyy
           7             yyyy
           8             zzzz
           9             zzzz
           10            zzzz
           11            zzzz
           12            zzzz")

library(dplyr)
group_by(d, Email) %>%
    slice(2)
#    Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#    Groups: Email
#      Number Email
#    1      2  xxxx
#    2      7  yyyy
#    3      9  zzzz
```

Comment: or to make it clear that `d` is not a grouping variable: `d %>% group_by(Email) %>% slice(2)`